# Android compiler error?

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio

Why raise Android Studio error when adding a string to an array? Cleaned, restarted Android Studio. What else I can do?

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.add("");
```

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#put%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: there is no method called add defined in JSONArray. Use put

Answer (score 0):

You can not add `String` using add() method as it's not defined in `JSONArray` you need to use `put()` method to do that as follows.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put("string value");
```

If you want to add `JSONObject` add it as follows

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("val", 4);
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put("");
```